# Changing background-color of an element in CSS using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Basically I want to change the background color of an element in CSS using JavaScript at the click of a button.

So far my CSS looks something like this:

```
div.box {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#FF2400;
}
```

It needs to change dynamically to a choice of several colors, just with multiple buttons will do (Each being a different color).

Comment: You can use jquery : http://api.jquery.com/css/, or use the DOM to change the style like this for instance: document.body.yourelementname.style.backgroundColor = "#FECE03"

Comment: You find anything helpful here?

Answer (score 8):

Done: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/zmtU4/

Updated to be Non-jQuery.

HTML

```
<div id="box"></div><div id="box"></div>

<button type="button" onclick="button_click('red');">Red</button>
<button type="button" onclick="button_click('blue');">Blue</button>
<button type="button" onclick="button_click('green');">Green</button>
<button type="button" onclick="button_click('yellow');">Yellow</button>
<button type="button" onclick="button_click('purple');">Purple</button>​
```

Pure JavaScript

```
function button_click(color){
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor=color;
}​
```

Comment: -1 for jsfiddle only answer. -1 for jQuery-only solution for a question not tagged `jQuery`. +1 for a decent jsfiddle

Comment: @Jamiec Pure JS solution. Code included. Waiting for your +1.

Comment: I didnt downvote your answer, I explained why you (probably) got downvoted. I'll upvote this to even it out

Answer (score 1):

The vanilla-javascript way to do this is to get a reference to the element and use `style.backgroundColor` to change the color:

for example, if the div has an id of `myBox` you would use

```
document.getElementById("myBox").style.backgroundColor="#000000"; // change to black
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/QWgcp/

Incidentally, if you're doing a lot of this kind of manipulation frameworks such as jQuery provide you with some help in writing the code. The same functionality using jQuery would be a bit simpler:

```
$('#myBox').css('background-color','#000000');
```

Comment: Removed my DV as you have it in your fiddle. OP asked for buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Do I correctly understand that you don't want to change single element, but CSS rule instead, so all matching elements would be affected? Here's an example how to dynamically change style in your example to blue color:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.box{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#FF2400;
}
</style>
<script>
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[0] // Of course if you have more than one sheet you'll have to find it among others somehow
    var rulesList = sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules // some older browsers have it that way
    var rule = rulesList[0] // same for rules - more than one and you'll have to iterate to find what you need
    rule.style.backgroundColor = 'blue' // and voila - both boxes are now blue
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just assign this piece as 'click' event handler to button and you're set.